# How do I know whether the row was not found or data haven't change with update?

Tags: mysql, sql

I use an SQL to update article content by article id:

```
UPDATE article SET content=? WHERE article_id=?;
```

If there is no article with this id or the content haven't change, both return 0 rows affected.

Is there an approach to distinguish these two conditions?

Comment: Both are same.1)There is no article with the id at present and 2)old article id changed to new value. So nothing to distinguish, Same for content

Comment: try [mysqli::$info](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.info.php). See Michael's comment at [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to mysql [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) it should be possible by setting `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` flag:

> For UPDATE statements, the affected-rows value by default is the
>   number of rows actually changed. If you specify the CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS
>   flag to mysql_real_connect() when connecting to mysqld, the
>   affected-rows value is the number of rows “found”; that is, matched by
>   the WHERE clause.

Comment: Although CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS was specified, it still make no difference for can't aware if the content changed or not.

Comment: Because there is only one value was returned by mysql.

Comment: It will only allow you to know if an article with the id exists or not.